# Can’t remove liquidity on uniswap

Tags: solidity, uniswap, ethereumjs, liquidity-provider, uniswapv2

I’m having issue removing my lp from uniswap 0xbeF4fB0BE483c74667aB6Fb5f3C1fCdc7b4eC073
Please help check the contract out

Comment: It would be more helpful if you included the UniswapV2Pair code here, as well as any additional information that may help us understand what happened. After briefly looking at it, it seems that you may be able to get your funds if you use the `burn` function since the contract holds almost a billion "SHIBAR". Also, a note for the future that always holds true: **NEVER** send real funds to a smart contract unless you completely understand every line of code in it.